# The contravariant mapping space represented by a homotopical classifying space (e.g. BG)

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, cohomology, infinity-categories, principal-bundles

In classical homotopy theory, there are a number of spaces which are important because they represent an interesting functor on $\operatorname{Ho(Top)}$; for example, $K(G,n)$ represents singular cohomology and $BG$ represents principal $G$-bundles. However, modern homotopy theorists know that the homotopy category is merely the truncation of a much richer structure, namely the $\infty$-category $\operatorname{Spaces}$, and both of these examples then yield representable functors from this $\infty$-category to itself. The conventional interpretation would appear to suggest that these spaces should be thought of as an "enriched" or "coherent" version of cohomology and vector bundles. Is this the case? What do these spaces look like, and are there any interesting results known about them?

Comment: If $G$ is a group-like $\mathbb E_1$-monoid, then spaces (or *anima* d'après Clausen–Scholze) over $BG$ precisely corresponds to $G$-equivariant anima, and this correspondence is functorial.

Comment: Well, for example $\mathrm{Map}(X,BG)$ is equivalent to the (nerve of the) topological groupoid of principal $G$-bundles on $X$, as long as $X$ is paracompact Hausdorff. Similarly $\mathrm{Map}(X,K(G,n))$ has the homotopy type of the simplicial abelian group corresponding to the connective cover of $C^{-*}(X;G)[n]$.

Comment: @DenisNardin Thank you, that's quite useful. I haven't actually seen a definition for the topological groupoid of principal $G$-bundles on a space; do you know where I could find one? (Other than "the functor represented by $BG$", of course.)

Comment: @DoronGrossman-Naples I added a quick explanation of the $G$-bundles case (with a sketch of the proof). Hopefully it's helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $G$ be a topological group and $X$ be a paracompact Hausdorff topological space. For simplicity let us assume that $G$ has the homotopy type of a CW complex, although a lot of this answer does not need it. Then we can define the simplicial category of principal $G$-bundles over $X$ in the following way:

- Its objects are principal $G$-bundles $p:P\to X$
- Given two objects $p:P\to X$ and $p':P'\to X$, the simplicial set $\operatorname{Map}(p,p')$ has as $n$ simplices the equivariant continuous maps $f:P\times |\Delta^n|\to P'\times|\Delta^n|$ over $X\times|\Delta^n|$, where $|\Delta^n|=\{(t_0,\dots,t_n)\mid \sum_i t_i=1\}$ is the topological $n$-simplex.

Note that all the mapping simplicial sets are Kan complexes. Therefore we can take its simplicial nerve and we get an $\infty$-category. In fact it is easily seen to be an $\infty$-groupoid, a.k.a. a space, $\operatorname{Bun}_G(X)$, which I will call the **space of principal $G$-bundles over $X$**. Note that it is canonically pointed by the trivial bundle.

With some effort this can be made controvariantly functorial in $X$, with the functoriality given by the pullback of bundles (as usual, this is accomplished by constructing a suitable fibration over the category of topological spaces -- the details are left as an exercise).

I am going to claim that $\operatorname{Bun}_G(X)$ is equivalent to $\operatorname{Map}(X,BG)$ where $BG$ is the classifying space of $G$.

The quickest proof I know of this fact is by proving that $\operatorname{Bun}_G(-)$ is a sheaf on paracompact Hausdorff spaces for the open covering topology (this requires some work -- in particular you have to show that the restriction map $\operatorname{Map}(p,p')\to \operatorname{Map}(p|_U,p'|_U)$ to an open subset is a Kan fibration).

Then it is easy to see that its sheaf $\pi_0$ is trivial and that $\Omega\operatorname{Bun}_G(-)$ is the constant sheaf at $G$ (this follows from the fact that if $L$ is a space homotopy equivalent to a CW-complex, the constant sheaf at the weak homotopy type of $L$ is given by the simplicial mapping space $U\mapsto \operatorname{Map}(U,L)$, by combining Corollary 7.1.4.4 and Proposition 7.1.5.1 in Higher Topos Theory). Therefore the recognition theorem for loopspaces in an $\infty$-topos shows that $\operatorname{Bun}_G(-)$ is the constant sheaf at $BG$. Finally, arguing as in [*Higher Algebra* Remark A.1.4] we see that the constant sheaf at $BG$ is exactly $\operatorname{Map}(-,BG)$.

---

A similar argument shows that the space of fiber bundles with fiber $F$ is equivalent to the space $\operatorname{Map}(X,B\operatorname{Homeo}(F))$, where $\operatorname{Homeo}(F)$ is the simplicial group of homeomorphisms of $F$.

Comment: Why is ΩBun_G(−) the constant sheaf on G?

Comment: @DmitriPavlov It's the automorphism sheaf of the trivial $G$-bundle, which can be checked to be $G$ ($n$-simplices over $U$ are $G$-equivariant maps $G\times U\times \Delta^n\to G\times U$ over $U$, that is continuous maps $U\times\Delta^n\to G$)

Comment: Yes, so why is the sheaf with the n-simplices as indicated isomorphic to the constant sheaf on G (or rather Sing(G))?

Comment: @DmitriPavlov that's again Remark A.1.4 in Higher algebra, using the fact that $X$ is paracompact (precisely one should restrict to the basis of open $F_\sigma$ subsets of $X$, as in HTT.7.1.1)

Comment: Remark A.1.4 requires an additional condition from X, it is not applicable to arbitrary paracompact Hausdorff topological spaces.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov I'll add more details, but I did not mean to literally apply the results of remark A.1.4 (that does require an additional hypothesis), but merely the first sentence, giving a description of the constant sheaves. Precisely this follows from a combination of 7.1.4.4 and 7.1.5.1 in Higher Topos Theory (it is mildly frustrating that HTT does not contain the statement in a citeable form). But you are right that something funny is happening: the statement I am making is correct only when $G$ has the homotopy type of a CW complex. I still believe the sheaf $BG$ is representable (cont.)

Comment: by a topological space in the general case (at least if $G$ is Hausdorff), but this requires a lot more care than I am using in this answer (essentially one needs to carefully see how the geometric realization interacts with the functor from topological spaces to sheaves on paracompact Hausdorff spaces). For example, what should $BG$ be for $G$ a profinite group?

Comment: It seems that the (first part of) Remark A.1.4 needs BG to be homotopy equivalent to a CW-complex in order for the constant sheaf on BG to be representable by the space BG.  Assuming G is a CW-complex, how do you show that BG is homotopy equivalent to a CW-complex in this generality?

Comment: @DmitriPavlov That is true basically by definition - with $BG$ I'm indicating $|B \operatorname{Sing}(G)|$, since this is the object produced by the recognition theorem (replacing $G$ with $\operatorname{Sing}(G)$ is allowed since $G$ has the homotopy type of a CW complex)

Comment: Said it differently, the definition of $BG$ is given via the geometric realization of the bar construction, and this clearly commutes with pullbacks. So if $G$ is a constant sheaf, so is $BG$